# Black screen after logging in on "Ubuntu on xorg" in Ubuntu 22.04 lts

Tags: xorg, login-screen

I am new to Ubuntu and have some hiccups using the latest one, whenever I change to Ubuntu xorg on logout screen from the gear option everything changes to black can't even navigate what I am doing and the only way to back normal was to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch neither force shutdown anything wont work can any one  help me out.[the Ubuntu on xorg is causing this can I remove this option entirely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpqqR.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's because Ubuntu 22.04 LTS runs Wayland by default, and is installed to handle Wayland over X11/Xorg. Wayland essentially handles all the GFX stuff, in laymans terms, which would explain why Xorg isn't working as well in U22.04.

That being said, if you get stuck in a black screen & want to reboot, you should be able to do Ctrl + Alt + F1/F2/F3 to open a TTY / shell. From there, you can log in and should be able to force a reboot that would then see you at the login screen. From there, you should be able to use the gear icon to select the normal Ubuntu option, which would run Wayland.

Lemme know if this helps (and feel free to +1 if it does). :-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, if I press tctrl+alt+F1 a black box appears but I can't see any text not anything due to too much contrast or something idk it's showing a some movement when I move the cursor jst like a deep negetive film i Don't know how to explain this but to show it I had switch to xorg which will make me do an full installation of the software from scratch .